# Prolog Set List's Head

Tags: prolog

```
append([],U,U).
append([X|U1],U2,[W|U3]) :- **W  = X** , append(U1,[X|U2],[I|Quyruk]) , 
                            **W  = I**, U3 = Quyruk .
```

This code appends first two lists when I delete   **"W  is X".**

This code has unnecessary variables like "W is X" but they are about  my question.

When I set any value to "W"  between ":-"  and  ",append..." like **"W is X"** or **"W = 3"** or **"W = 6"** --   *returns false*.

Why can't I set any value to the W at that position in code  but I CAN set "W  = I" at the end of the code?

The query is    `append([1,2],[3],U).` I want to get `[2,1,3]` at this code 
at `append([1,2,3],[4,5,6],U).` I want to get `[3,2,1,4,5,6]`.

`append([1],[2,3],U).` returns `[1,2,3]` , when I take the length of first list "1" (when first list only has one element) the code is perfect ; but when I take the length of first list >1 (when first list has more than one element) the code returns false.

Comment: Why not just: `my_append(L1, L2, L3) :- reverse(L1, L4), append(L4, L2, L3).`?  In prolog `=` doesn't assign like it does in other languages. It *unifies*. Once a variable has been instantiated through unification, you can't change it inside of a clause. So once you do `W = X`, this unifies them and `W = I` will fail always unless `I` and `X` (`I` and `W`) happen to be instantiated with the same value.

Comment: append([1],[2,3],U).     ->    returns   [1,2,3]  ,

   when i take the   length of first list "1" (when first list only has one element) the code is perfect     ; 
   but when i take  the   length of first list  >1 (when first list has more than one element)  the code returns false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In prolog, you can't *assign* variables, and then *reassign* them. Variables are unified and instantiated. Once instantiated, they cannot be re-instantiated inside of a clause. So if you have this inside of a clause:

```
W = X,
...
W = I,
```

Then first `W` is unified with `X` (`=/2` is the unification operator). That means they either both now have the same value instantiated (if at least one was instantiated before), or their values will be forced to be identical instantiation later in the clause. When `W = I` is encountered later, then `I` must be unifiable with `W` or the clause will fail. If `I` has a specific value instantiated that is different from the instantiation of `W` (and, therefore, `X`), the clause will necessarily fail.

Let's see it happen (note I changed the name to `my_append` since Prolog rejects redefining the built-in predicate, `append`):

```
my_append([],U,U).
my_append([X|U1], U2, [W|U3]) :-
    W = X,
    my_append(U1, [X|U2], [I|Quyruk]),
    write('I = '), write(I), write('; W = '), write(W), nl,
    W = I,
    U3 = Quyruk.
```

If we run:

```
?- my_append([1], [1,2], L).
I = 1; W = 1

L = [1,2,3]

yes
```

Life is good. Now let's try:

```
| ?- my_append([1,2], [3,4], L).
I = 2; W = 2   % This will be OK
I = 2; W = 1   % Uh oh... trouble

no
```

Prolog cannot unify `1` and `2`, as I described above. They are two different values. So the predicate fails due to the `W = I` statement.

The solution is a little simpler than what you're attempting (although you are very close):

```
% Append empty to list gives the same list
my_append([], U, U).

% Append of [X|U1] and U2 is just append U1 and [X|U2]
% Or, thought of another way, you are moving elements of the first list
% over to the head of the second one at a time
my_append([X|U1], U2, U3) :-
    my_append(U1, [X|U2], U3).

| ?- my_append([1,2,3],[4,5,6],L).

L = [3,2,1,4,5,6]

yes
```

The essence of this was in your code. Those other variables were just getting in the way (as C.B. pointed out). :)

Comment: append([1],[2,3],U). -> returns [1,2,3] , when i take the length of first list "1" (when first list only has one element) the code is perfect ; but when i take the length of first list >1 (when first list has more than one element) the code returns false 
why  when the length of first list  is greater than 1  ( >1)  the code return false ?

Comment: @user3174737 see my updated answer showing an example of my explanation of the failure.

Answer (score 0):

The `is` operator is specifically used to compare or unify integers. `W = I` Is attempting to unify W with I (regardless of type). When you Unify `W` with `X` (assuming X is an integer), you have already unified `W`, and if `X\=I` (doesn't unify) you will return false.

In your example, `W` unifies with `1`, but then you try to unify it with `2`.

You have a lot of unnecessary variables, here is a very simple implementation of append:

```
append([],XS,XS).

append([X|XS],YS,[X|ZS]):- append(XS,YS,ZS).
```

To understand whats going wrong with your code, lets walk through it

```
append([],U,U).
append([X|U1],U2,[W|U3]) :- W is X , append(U1,[X|U2],[I|Quyruk]) , W = I, U3 = Quyruk .
?-append([1,2,3],[4,5,6],U).
```

I will use `X1,X2,...` to differentiate between different bindings.

In the first call, `X` unifies with `1`, `U1` unifies with `[2,3]` and `U2` unifies with `[4,5,6]`. `W and U3` are not yet bound before going into the horn clause.

`W is X` unifies `W` with `1`.

`append(U1,[X|U2],[I|Quyruk])` is calling `append([2,3],[1,4,5,6],[I|Quyruk])`. Already you should see that your recursion isn't working correctly.

Comment: When i write "W = X" or  "W = 3"  it return false again , why         "W = X"  false  "W = I" true ?

Comment: @user3174737 I would take a look at your recursion, and why you are unifying variables when you can just use the original ones instead. Like, why do you unify `U3` with `Quyruk` when you can just use `Quyruk`?

Comment: I am  beginner in prolog , i know the best answer is
append([],XS,XS).
append([X|XS],YS,[X|ZS]):- append(XS,YS,ZS).

But i am trying different way

Comment: I am not trying to find the best solution , i only want to know why i cant set   "W = 3" or "W = X" , what is the problem in back stage ?

I cant set "W = I" at the last of code , why at the begin it returns false but at the last it doesnt make problem

Comment: To understand whats going wrong with my code, lets walk through  that

append([1,2],[3],U).        I want to get  [2,1,3]  at this code

at append([1,2,3],[4,5,6],U).   ı want to get [3,2,1,4,5,6]